# Segue not passing data between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9

I am making an iOS app that uses payment methods.

At the moment I am trying to work on the checkout flow, which contains an OderFormViewController and a CheckoutTableViewController as you can see below:

[image]

I connected both by dragging a segue, as highlighted in blue. I also added a segue identifier for my segue.

I called the first view controller as `E_OrderFormViewController`(Its title is Shipping Address), and in it I created an `IBAction`for my Continue button and also used `-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` to pass in the information.

I also have an Order model, with some properties in it. On my CheckoutTableViewController, I have got my labels and orderInfo as public properties, so the first view controller one can access it.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Order : NSObject

@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *shippingName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *shippingAddress;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *shippingCity;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *shippingState;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *shippingZip;


@end


//E_OrderFormViewController.m

#import "E_OrderFormViewController.h"
#import "F_CheckoutTableViewController.h"

...

#pragma mark - My Actions
- (IBAction)storePaymentInfoProceedToConfirmation:(id)sender {
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toCheckout" sender:self];
}

#pragma mark - Navigation
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

  if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toCheckout"]) {
    F_CheckoutTableViewController *checkoutView = segue.destinationViewController;

    //Store Information and pass it to next view
    checkoutView.orderInfo.shippingName = self.txtFieldNameOnCard.text;

    NSLog(@"Shipping Name Stored: %@",checkoutView.orderInfo.shippingName);
  }

}
```

My `NSLog` always returns (null) for whatever text I type inside my first textField, which is the one I am testing first.

Here is my `CheckoutTableViewController`, with its public property. The `orderInfo`is listed here. I am using it to pass in the information, as I mentioned above:

```
//F_CheckoutTableViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface F_CheckoutTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic)Order *orderInfo;

@end
```

On my `viewDidLoad`, on my destination view controller, I did:

```
//F_CheckoutTableViewController.m

@implementation F_CheckoutTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

  //Load all information

  self.labelShippingName.text = self.orderInfo.shippingName;

  NSLog(@"Typed Name: %@",self.orderInfo.shippingName);

}
```

I just pasted the `viewDidLoad` as a reference, as I am aware if my `NSLog` in my `prepareForSegue` is not returning anything, the information is not being passed.

I really don't know where the error is. I searched in a couple of threads here on StackOverFlow, and none of them helped me, one which seems to be similar, is this one, but it didn't help with my issue:

[Multiple segues not passing Object data between themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052950/multiple-segues-not-passing-object-data-between-themselves)

This seems to be pretty simple, but I am making some mistake that I can not find.

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

orderInfo must be null, because you didn't initialize it, therfore you cannot set its properties... so you got 2 options:

```
checkoutView.orderInfo = [[OrderInfo alloc]init];
checkoutView.orderInfo.shippingName = self.txtFieldNameOnCard.text;
```

or change your property from:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)Order *orderInfo;
```

to:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *shippingName ;
```

Comment: Good catch. He should also check `self.txtFieldNameOnCard.text` actually has content, maybe the outlet is not hooked up from IB.

Comment: Could you translate in Swift, I need help on this too!

Comment: Hi @meda, thanks a lot for that. I initialized the property and it worked fine.

Comment: Also @jere, thanks for the tip, I also checked the IB. All good guys.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the storyboard set up, you are using Textfield in Shipping Address View Controller, it may miss the delegation of Textfield to its controller.